# coffescript file does not execute properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to include notifications in my rails app and I am following this tutorial to the letter: https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications

Everything works fine up to the moment where I want to dynamically append the notifications to the html.

It seems as if the coffescript file doesn't execute at all. Even when I just want to console.log the div it's not executed

[application.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByZtb.png)

**navbar.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.is_a?(User) %>
  <div class="icon">
    <div class="btn-group dropleft" data-behavior="notifications">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
       haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data- 
       behavior="notifications-link">
          <i class="far fa-bell icon-selector"></i><span data- 
            behavior="unread-count"></span>
          <p>Notifications</p>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" data-behavior="notification-items">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ....
```

**notifications.js.coffee**

```
class Notifications
constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
    @setup() if @notifications.length > 0

setup: ->
    console.log(@notifications)
    $.ajax(
        url: "/notifications.json"
        dataType: "JSON"
        method: "GET"
        success: @handleSuccess
    )

jQuery ->
new Notifications
```

Comment: Did you add the file to the application.js manifest?

Comment: Hey ! Not explicitly but I included the require tree. which loads all files in the asset pipeline. Also i know that the 'notifications.js.coffee loads because if I remove everythign and put an alert message it executes. Do you have any other idea? Im happy to share my repo

Comment: do you have any error on the browser's console? if you put the line `debugger` enywhere, execution will stop and you can debug this step by step in real time

Comment: That's the thing I dont have any errors :p I know that the page loads and I think the coffeescript even compiles to Javascript because I can see it in the asset pipeline file but it's like nothing happens on the browser side..

Comment: is the .coffee copied with the indentation you have? because contructor and setup should be indented and `new Notifications` should be indented too

Comment: Yes the indentation is correct. Since I use Rails 5 I also don't have to include it in my gemfile since it's there by default right? I included a screenshot of the compiled application.js file that I accessed via http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js maybe it helps? Thanks for your effort btw

Comment: I would add a `debugger` line before `new Notifications` (maybe another one inside constructor and another inside setup cause I'm not good at debugging step by step hahaha) and checking anything I can

Comment: Thanks that helped!! I now know where the error is! There's somethign wrong in the syntax, if you could take a look it would be awesome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183528/uncaught-reference-error-notification-not-defined