# uncaught reference error, notification not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to add notifications to my rails app. Basically I get them from a JSON endpoint and I try to fetch them and append them to my html using some Coffeescript[Here's the JSON array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiO7s.png).  The problem is in the handleSuccess method where I get uncaught reference error, notification not defined

**notifications.js.coffee**

```
 class Notifications
  constructor: ->
   @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")
   @setup() if @notifications.length > 0

  setup: ->
   $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
   console.log(data)
   items = $.map data, (notification) ->
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#{notification.url}'># 
      {notification.action} #{notification.notifiable.type}</a>"

jQuery ->
 new Notifications
```

**WHAT I get from localhost:3000/notifications.json**

[{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/10#list_10"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/10#list_10"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/10#list_10"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/10#list_10"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"},{"actor":"emanuelcoen","action":"liked","notifiable":{"type":"your list"},"url":"/lists/17#list_17"}]

Comment: Thanks for your help man! The problem is, I can't find the the error in the server logs. In the server logs I just see that on every page load it builds the JSON but I can't see where the error is afterwards. Can you maybe tell me where to look for it? Also: How come that it's not an array since I specifiy dataType JSON in the AJAX call?

Comment: What does `http://yourserver/notifications.json` return?

Comment: Updated the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation error in the function you are passing to your `$.map`. The  string below it has to be indented, otherwise it assumes you are passing an empty function to map, and the line after it raises an error as `notification` isn't defined.

```
  handleSuccess: (data) =>
   console.log(data)
   items = $.map data, (notification) ->
     "<a class='dropdown-item' href=''>#{notification.actor}</a>"
```

---

### Update

Regarding your comment that the notifications aren't showing on the page - you aren't calling any code to add the html string you are generating to the DOM. You could use [$.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for this.

```
  handleSuccess: (data) =>
   console.log(data)
   for notification in data
     @notifications.append(
       "<a class='dropdown-item' href=''>#{notification.actor}</a>")
```

There is no need to use `$.map` over the notifications array as we are just rendering them in another loop, so I replaced it with a single Coffeescript comprehension.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help :) The indentation worked I don't get any errors in the console anymore and I see the array in the console, but it's still not appending the html like it should. Any idea? I edited my answer to show the updated coffeescript file and the screenshot from the console.

Comment: Hi! It's not working with this code, I get a SyntaxError: [stdin]:18:1: unexpected indentation. when I change the identation the app works but nothing gets appended.

Comment: @EmanuelCoen Sorry about that, I left out a set of parenthesis. I updated the code

Comment: Ups. I thought I had included the link, sorry :D https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications

Comment: @EmanuelCoen you missed out two lines after the `$.map` in the tutorial: `$("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(items.length)` `$("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)`. The `.html` call is similar to append, but it will overwrite what was inside the element rather than adding to it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Works perfectly :)